# Converting labels to Annotation using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, labeling, annotation

I am a beginner in GIS (for graduate school) and am using the GIS Tutorial Basic Workbook 1 for ArcGIS10.  In Chapter 1 of this text, there is a "Convert labels to annotation" section which I cannot follow.  When I right-click the item, "Convert labels to annotion" is not an option.

How do I implement this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to right click the layer in the Table of Contents to get the option to convert labels to annotation.  Try following the example in [Exercise 3a: Converting labels to annotation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000001w000000.htm).

More help can be found at  [Converting labels to annotation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s80000001r000000.htm).